Calculating $\text{ord}(0,\frac{1}{\sin^2(z)}-\frac{1}{z^2})$
Is the following procedure valid?
$$\begin{align*} \operatorname{ord}\left(0,\frac{1}{\sin^2(z)}-\frac{1}{z^2}\right)
&=\operatorname{ord}\left(0,\frac{z^2-\sin^2(z)}{(z\sin(z))^2}\right)\\[9 pt]
&=\operatorname{ord}(0,z^2-\sin^2(z))-2\operatorname{ord}(0,z\sin(z))\\[9 pt]  
&=\operatorname{ord}(0,z+\sin(z))+\text{ord}(0,z-\sin(z))-2\times2 \\  
&= 1+3-2\times2=0
\end{align*}$$
But this doesn't agree with the output of WolframAlpha given here.

It's not clear in what sense the output of Wolfram Alpha disagrees with your result. Indeed, if you expand the function near $z=0$ then WolframAlpha yields $$\frac{1}{\sin^2 z}-\frac{1}{z^2}=\frac13 +\frac{z^2}{15}+\frac{2z^4}{189}+\cdots$$ So the function does appear to be analytic near $z=0$, in agreement with what you found.

Does Wolfram classify $0$
based on the set of poles $2nπ
, n≠0$
, which are poles of order $2$,
by default?
